# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined React

Tags: reactjs, undefined, lowercase

im new to stackoverflow and react,i have some problems.
Here is code.

```js
onSearchChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({ searchfiled: event.target.value })
}

render() {
  const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robots => {
    return robots.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfiled.toLowerCase());
  })
  return(
    <div className='tc'>
      <h1>Robofriends</h1>
      <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
      <CardList robots={filteredRobots}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you provide rest of the code of this component!

Comment: Here you go,thanks :) [link]https://pastebin.com/ah8pSTeF

Comment: is the `this.state.searchfilled` variable initalized ?

Comment: @JorgeGarcía Yes :D

Comment: @CarlosSaizOrteu Here it is https://pastebin.com/dbqHsG95

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, you got a typing error in the filter. You got this:

```
const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robots =>{
return robots.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfiled.toLowerCase());
})
```

It should be this:

```
const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robot =>{
return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
})
```

You where mistaking searchField using searchFiled.

Moreover in the filter function you are using robots which is the same name as the imported "robots" which can lead to mistakes. Use robot insteadd.

Comment: Thank you very much,im new to this and im trying hard to understand the basic of react .